# "chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json"

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server

I am trying to install transmission on my Ubuntu 14.04 server and I am unsure whether to skip this part or not. I am trying to give permissions to a folder with

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

but the output is

```
chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Am I doing something wrong or should I just skip this part or what?

I am following instructions from here: [Install Transmission with web interface on Ubuntu](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-transmission-web-interface-on-ubuntu-1204/2/), and I am at the end of step 5.

Update: Output of `ls -l /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root debian-transmission 51 Oct 6 18:12 /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json -> /home/cam/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

I guess the file doesn't exist because when I run `cd /home/cam/.config/transmission-daemon`, then run `dir`, nothing shows up.

Comment: Having a symlink from a system directory to your home directory is... not very clean. In any case, does the file `/home/cam/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json` exist?

Comment: @fkraiem, I guess the file doesn't exist because when I perform the command `cd /home/cam/.config/transmission-daemon` and the do `dir` nothing shows up. I would imagine the config file is a template so I don't want to just make my own. How could I transfer the config file there? Although I would have thought the instructions I'm following would have taken that into account.

Comment: Normally you should have copied it there using the command `sudo cp -a /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json transmission-daemon/` from the guide. Maybe you were in the wrong directory when you ran it (this guide is really not very good), try `cp /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon`.

Comment: @fkraiem, I already did that, `mkdir /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon,
sudo cp -a /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json transmission-daemon/,
sudo chgrp -R debian-transmission /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon,
sudo chmod -R 770 /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon` thats from the instructions

Comment: Yes, but because the command in the guide uses a relative path for the `cp` command, it will only work if you are in the directory `~/.config/transmission-daemon` when you run it. Since apparently the file has not been copied correctly, you probably were in another directory, so you need to run the command again to copy the file in the correct directory.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed my dangling symlink error by using the full path, as this site suggests:
https://www.howtofixthis.com/categories/linux/chmod-cannot-operate-on-dangling-symlink

So I did:

```
ln -s `pwd`/[executable] executable.bin
```

where the backticks (`) indicate [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but I created the symlink with the root user and tried to chmod with another user. Make sure you use the same user for both actions...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have missed or been in the wrong directory when issuing the command below while following the poorly written tutorial.

`sudo cp -a /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json transmission-daemon/`

If you didn't already remove the original you can resolve the problem by retracing your steps and reissuing the command after `cd /home/user/.config/`

If the file no longer exists you should re-install as suggested by Warpigs answer

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
```

and then...

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
```

go to `/etc/transmission-daemon/` and check if `setting.json` is back.